# How to handle checked iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator

for debug mode in VS2013 I receive an out of range exception if I add a constant value to an iterator and this iterator will go out of range afterwards.

For example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {
    std::vector<unsigned char> data(10, 0);

    auto it = data.begin();

    while (it != data.end()) {
        if ((it + 3) <= data.end()) {
            it += 3;
        }
        else {
            it = data.end();
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In the fourth run of the `while`-loop the check `it + 3 <= data.end()` fails and the exception is thrown.

A short workaround for the VS compiler would be to insert `#define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 0` that disables the option for checked iterators in debug mode.

But I would appreciate a better, common solution that will work for both, VS and GCC compiler!
I'm sure there already exists a way by the STL to handle iterator distances and checks like this :) but I don't know it yet...

Comment: Why not `for (auto it = data.begin(); std::distance(it, data.end()) > 3; it += 3){//your loop}`

Comment: an iterator before the first element or past the last element + 1 is undefined behaviour. (note that just getting this iterator — even without dereferencing it — is UB)

Comment: Note: the complaint from the compiler is because you are doing something "illegal", it's only a symptom, and thus your work-around is not really one: you are trading a well-understood and reproducible symptom for an undefined set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better common solution is the following

```
while ( std::distance( it, data.end() ) >= 3 )
{
    // some code
    std::advance( it, 3 );
    // some code
}
```

Or

```
while ( it != data.end() )
{
    // some code
    std::advance( it, std::min<int>( 3, std::distance( it, data.end() ) ) );
    // some code
}
```

The choice between these two variants depends on whether you want to process the iterator at least one time even if data.end() - it is less than 3.

If a non-random access iterator is used then the loop can look as

```
while ( it != data.end() )
{
    // some code
    ( ++it != data.end() ) && ( ++it != data.end() ) && ( ++it != data.end() );
    // some code
}
```

Comment: `while ( std::distance( it, data.end() ) >= 3 )` maybe?

Comment: That's slightly inefficient though, on non RandomAccessIterators, because you end up going from `it` to `min(end, it+3)` twice: once for `distance` and once for `advance`. A "checked" advance would thus be more efficient in those cases.

Comment: @Matthieu M I agree with you. In case of a non random access iterator the body of the loop should contain expression  ( ++it != data.end() ) && ( ++it != data.end() ) && ( ++it != data.end() );

Answer (score 1):

That's because `end()` points to the element *beyond* the last actual element of the vector. So your condition `if ((it + 3) <= data.end())` will eventually evaluate to `end() + 1` (when `it` already equals `end()`), which is invalid. To fix it, change it to `if ((it + 3) < data.end())`.

To reiterate: the last available element of a vector, or any other STL container, is located at `end() - 1`. If the container is empty, `begin()` is the same as `end()`. It is always an error to dereference an iterator pointing to `end()`.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't make a difference. So I know that the past-the-end-iterator points to the element beyond the last one. But for the comparison only the addresses the iterators/(pointers) point to should be relevant. So the iterator returned by end() would never be dereferenced in my case I think.

Comment: Wrong: `it+3` is equally invalid when `it==end()-1`.

Comment: @MSalters: That explains why my solution doesn't help.